# AssertionError: Manifest file not found: out/dreqManifest.txt

Tags: python

When I run file this error occurs:

```
AssertionError: Manifest file not found: out/dreqManifest.txt
```

Log recored is below:

```
runfile('C:/Users/rakesh/Climate/cmip6_data.py', wdir='C:/Users/rakesh/Climate')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-1fc2857eabc7>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/rakesh/Climate/cmip6_data.py', wdir='C:/Users/rakesh/Climate')

  File "C:\Users\rakesh\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\rakesh\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/rakesh/Climate/cmip6_data.py", line 1141, in <module>
    dreq = loadDreq(manifest='out/dreqManifest.txt' )

  File "C:/Users/rakesh/Climate/cmip6_data.py", line 932, in __init__
    self.c = config( thisdoc=dreqXML, configdoc=configdoc, useShelve=useShelve,strings=strings,manifest=manifest,configOnly=configOnly)

  File "C:/Users/rakesh/Climate/cmip6_data.py", line 512, in __init__
    assert os.path.isfile( manifest ), 'Manifest file not found: %s' % manifest

AssertionError: Manifest file not found: out/dreqManifest.txt
```

Comment: you are on Linux?

Comment: no i am not using linux working on windows

Comment: try to use \ instead of /, or you cand use os to create dynamic path

Comment: Thank you its fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `/` isntead of `\`.

Because `/` are use in Linux path and `\` are use in Windows path.